# Beginner in SQL Server 2014 Express, vb.net, cummon server ( Mass storage )

Tags: sql-server, database, vb.net, ado.net, database-connection

I developed an app with vb.net to update a SQL Server database.

The app is connected with SQL Server in my computer and seems working very well.
But my target is to put this database in the common mass storage to be updated with this app from 20 people (20 client PC).

My questions are:

- how to do to install the database in the common mass storage?
- should the SQL Server Express be installed in the 20 client computers?
- how to connect the app to the database (located in the common server) using ADO.net?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends.  If everybody is suppose to use the same data I would look at putting up a sql server that everyone can access on the network. If the data needs to be used from computers outside of a local network I would look at getting a database from a web host.  For these instances you would have to update the server to your connection string to the url of the new sql server.   If everyone is using there own data it is ok to use there own sql express instance.